# Login using fetch but now with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Im doing a Login submit for my React-Adonis application, my Submit is working fine, but i need to change the fetch im using for axios.
How can i do that?

I installed axios dependence and imported already

```
import axios from 'axios'; 

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current!.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current!.value;

    if (enteredPassword.length < 6) {
      toast.warn('Password must be 6 or more digits.');
      return;
    }
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3333/login';
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: enteredEmail,
        password: enteredPassword,
        returnSecureToken: true,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.token) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(authActions.login(data.token));
          }, 1000);
          return;
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Can you please clearly state what your problem is?

Comment: I'd start with the Axios docs ~ https://github.com/axios/axios#axios

Comment: If it's working with `fetch`, why switch to Axios (or anything else for that matter)?

Comment: @Phil Maybe IE support or something? (I hope not)

Comment: I didnt know there's a axios documentation, it solved my issue. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend you to read axios [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios) first. But in summary, you will to create a axios instance and change the fetch with something like:

```
axios.post(url, JSON.stringify({
    email: enteredEmail,
    password: enteredPassword,
    returnSecureToken: true,
  })
```

This will return a promise so you can keep using your `.then / .catch`

Comment: This won't post the data as `application/json`

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, i really didnt know that it exists. JSON.stringify didnt work in axios, i send the data after the url,     axios
      .post(url, {
        email: enteredEmail,
        password: enteredPassword,
        returnSecureToken: true,
      })

Answer (score -1):

```
  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current!.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current!.value;

    if (enteredPassword.length < 6) {
      toast.warn('Password must be 6 or more digits.');
      return;
    }
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3333/login';

    axios
      .post(url, {
        email: enteredEmail,
        password: enteredPassword,
        returnSecureToken: true,
      })
      .then((res: any) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          if (res.data.token) {
            toast.success('Logged In with sucess!', {
              position: 'bottom-center',
              hideProgressBar: true,
            });
            setTimeout(() => {
              dispatch(authActions.login(res.data.token));
            }, 1000);
            return;
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        toast.error('Email or Password wrong.');
      });
  };
```